# AJAX call not working in React once I change state

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

So I'm currently writing something due tomorrow in React. I have a component that looks like:

```
var PartOne = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        month: 1,
        day: 1,
        year: 2016,
        loading: false,
        res: '',
        count: 0
    };
},

_onSelectDay (option) {
    this.setState({day: option})
},

_onSelectMonth (option) {
    this.setState({month: option})
},

_onSelectYear (option) {
    this.setState({year: option})
},

onSubmit: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.persist();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/partOne',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            month: this.state.month,
            day: this.state.day,
            year: this.state.year
        },
        success: function(data) {
            this.setState({res: data.res});
        }.bind(this),
      });
},

render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                What is the total number of entries and exits across 
                &nbsp;
                <MonthSelector month={this.state.month} onSelect={this._onSelectMonth} />
                &nbsp;
                <DaySelector day={this.state.day} onSelect={this._onSelectDay} />
                &nbsp;
                <YearSelector year={this.state.year} onSelect={this._onSelectYear} />
                ?
                &nbsp;
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                <br />
                (The date must be between May 8, 2010, and September 16, 2016).
            </form>
            <div id="res">
                {this.state.res}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
});
```

If I load the page and hit submit, then the AJAX request goes through. However, if I change the date (and thereby change the state) and then hit submit, I get the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string
```

I'm not sure why this is the case. I'm using Chrome to view my page, although I can reproduce my code in Safari as well. Here is the HTML file that generates my code (there is a bit more to the react, but it's only the above component that's on the screen).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>MTA Turnstile Analyses</title>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="mount-point"></div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.2/react-dom.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.2/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/jsx" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='scripts/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```

Please let me know if I should provide extra information. I'd really appreciate the help since I'm in a tight timecrunch. Thanks!

Comment: What are these <MonthPicker /> and other two components. Have you defined them or are you using a library.

Comment: Sorry, I defined those before. They're just dropdown menus.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, the idea is that: I have a form, and when the user hits submit, an AJAX request is sent. But if I change the form, the request fails.

Comment: Yeah, but what do they pass `onSelect`? If they're just `select` elements, then `onSelect` you should be able to get `event.target.value`. It looks as though your `option` arg is not what you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

Change the following:

```
<MonthSelector month={this.state.month} onSelect={this._onSelectMonth(event.target.value)} />
&nbsp;
<DaySelector day={this.state.day} onSelect={this._onSelectDay(event.target.value)} />
&nbsp;
<YearSelector year={this.state.year} onSelect={this._onSelectYear(event.target.value)} />
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Change you _onSelectDay, onSelectMonth and onSelectYear functions like this'

```
_onSelectDay (e) {
    this.setState({day: e.target.value});
},

_onSelectMonth (e) {
    this.setState({month: e.target.value});
},

_onSelectYear (e) {
    this.setState({year: e.target.value});
},
```

**Code:**

```
var PartOne = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
        month: 1,
        day: 1,
        year: 2016,
        loading: false,
        res: '',
        count: 0
    };
},

_onSelectDay (e) {
    this.setState({day: e.target.value});
},

_onSelectMonth (e) {
    this.setState({month: e.target.value});
},

_onSelectYear (e) {
    this.setState({year: e.target.value});
},

onSubmit: function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.persist();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/partOne',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            month: this.state.month,
            day: this.state.day,
            year: this.state.year
        },
        success: function(data) {
            this.setState({res: data.res});
        }.bind(this),
      });
},

render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                What is the total number of entries and exits across 
                &nbsp;
                <MonthSelector month={this.state.month} onSelect={this._onSelectMonth)} />
                &nbsp;
                <DaySelector day={this.state.day} onSelect={this._onSelectDay} />
                &nbsp;
                <YearSelector year={this.state.year} onSelect={this._onSelectYear} />
                ?
                &nbsp;
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                <br />
                (The date must be between May 8, 2010, and September 16, 2016).
            </form>
            <div id="res">
                {this.state.res}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Fixed the problem :) :)