# How to use jquery ajax in reactjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I want to use jquery ajax in reactjs. but it return can not post insert.php.
and another question is how can i access this.state object and this.setSate on success?

```
class Name extends React.Component{
   constructor(){
      super();
      this.state={name:''}
  }
  btnClick=()=>{
    $.ajax({
        url:'insert.php',
        type:'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({me:'Hamid'}),
        success:function (data,status ,xhr) {
            alert(data.name)
        }
    })

}
render() {
    return(
        <div><span>{this.state.name}</span>
        <button type='button' onClick={this.btnClick}>show</button>
        </div>
    )
}
}

 ReactDOM.render(<Name/>,document.getElementById('root1'));
```

Comment: You can import the jquery library for this, but you can use `fetch` as well

Comment: I imported jquery library.

Comment: Why would you want to use jquery ajax in React.js, search for better ways rather then going with a first solution

Comment: because i'm more familiar with jquery than other APis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At First should locate php Files in PHP server, and set header something like this:

```
<?php
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000');
```

and then, to have access to 'this' in success or error properties that their values are functions we should bind 'this' to these functions or use arrow functions as values of success and error.

bind 'this' to functions:

```
   $.ajax({
    url:'http://localhost/react/api/insert.php',
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({me:'Hamid'}),
    success:function (data,status ,xhr) {
         this.setState({name: data.name});
    }.bind(this)
})
```

Arrow function:

> With arrow functions, this will always represent the object that defined the arrow function.[W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_events.asp)

```
        $.ajax({
           url:"http://localhost/react/api/insert.php",
          type:'post',
          dataType:'json',
          data: JSON.stringify({me:'Hamid'}),
          success:(data, status,xhr) =>{
          this.setState({
             username:data.name
          });
        error:(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)=>  {
           this.setState({
               username:'error'
           });
        }
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have imported jquery correctly, it should be the same as any async http call in React:

```
btnClick=()=>{
    $.ajax({
        url:'insert.php',
        type:'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({me:'Hamid'}),
        success: (data,status ,xhr) => {
            this.setState({ name: data.name });
        }
    })
```

Comment: I think that this keyword in ajax function doesn't refer to the component then we cant access to this.Setstate @Davin Tryon

Comment: @Hamid if you use the arrow function, then the `this` context will be the class you are in.

Answer (score 0):

set useing this.setState({name: data.name});

```
class Name extends React.Component{
   constructor(){
      super();
      this.state={name:''}
  }
  btnClick=()=>{
    $.ajax({
        url:'insert.php',
        type:'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({me:'Hamid'}),
        success:function (data,status ,xhr) {
             this.setState({name: data.name});

        }
    })

}
render() {
    return(
        <div><span>{this.state.name}</span>
        <button type='button' onClick={this.btnClick}>show</button>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

Comment: the response is :Cannot POST /insert.php

Comment: @Hamid you need to check the directory/path of insert.php

Comment: I think that this keyword in ajax function doesn't refer to the component then we cant access to this.Setstate

Comment: @Hamid please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39607170/ajax-call-not-working-in-react-once-i-change-state

Comment: I think it can not find insert.php file!?